# Sketching the contour map of a function with several variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Consider the surface given by the function $f(x,y) = \frac{4}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-9}}$. Draw the level curves for the values $c = 1$ and $c = 2$. Be sure to label your axes to indicate the scale. Note: When graphing the equation $f(x, y) = c$ here, you will want to rearrange the equation to put it in a recognizable form. Hint: Get the variables out of the denominator and eliminate the radical.
>
> Determine any $y$-intercept(s) of $f$. Write the answer(s) as ordered triples and do not round any of the coordinates.

I was able to find and graph the domain of $f$ and was also able to find the range. However, I'm having a lot of trouble drawing the level curves -- I'm not even sure of the form I should rearrange the equation to. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$ \frac{4}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-9}}=c \implies  \frac{16}{{x^2+y^2-9}}=c^2\implies x^2+y^2=9+\frac {16}{c^2}$$

Do you recognize something here ?

Comment: Thank you! I've got it now. In terms of y-intercepts, would there be none, since f(x, y) = z could never equal 0, and in order for there to be a y-intercept, z = 0 and x = 0? Also, would the range be 0 to infinity?